# Determining which form element triggered by ENTER

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to detect when the ENTER key is pressed AND I need to know which form element triggered the event. I found code for detecting when the ENTER key is pressed but I can't determine the ID of the form element that triggered it.

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if( e.which == 13 )
        {
        alert( $(this) );               //This shows an object is accessible
        alert( $(this).attr("id") );    //This displays "undefined". Why? How do I determine the id of the object?
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's undefined because `this` refers to the selector, in your case `document`. See my answer for a possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that $(this).attr("id") was never going to return an id because it was triggered by a keypress, not by the form field that had the focus prior to the keypress, which is what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 2):

using event delegation you could try this code:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
    if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
       console.log(this.id);
    }
});
```

in your example your `$(this)` is the `document` object itself (and not the element that triggered the event)

Also note that this code works if all your `input` fields have an `id` attribute defined (otherwise `this.id` won't be defined for some elements)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
$('form input, form select, form radio').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
   $form = $(this).closest('form');
   alert($form.attr('id'))
   console.log($form);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmmq9/1/

If you have a browser with a console (like Chrome with DevTools or Firefox with Firebug) you can use `console.log` instead of `alert` which will give you much more information than the fact that it's an object.
But be sure do remove it after testing because otherwise IE will throw a javascript error.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. When I took all your code instead of just `this.form.id` it didn't produce an error. However, it doesn't display the ID of the form element either. It simply pops up the alert message with no info at all.

Comment: Does your form have an id? Do you have a browser with a console to see the value of `this`? If you have chrome just press Ctrl-J and refresh

Comment: I just found out that `inputElement.form` doesn't work in all browsers. I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, the form element itself does in fact have an ID attribute. I'd really be kicking myself if that's what the problem was. My browser does not have a console, at least I don't think it does. It's FF 13 but I don't have Firebug installed.